# Portlet.js Fail Query

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

When user tries to navigate away to another portal page before current page has finished loading, error message saying - `There was unexpected error. Please refresh the current page` comes up for the portlets which were loading before the redirection happened.
On debugging, it was found that it comes up from `portlet.js` and its `failed()` handler from Ajax call.

Can we restrict it for a specific portlet?

Thanks

Comment: Restrict what exactly?

Comment: This is default behaviour of Liferay that when portlet is rendered, ajax call is made, and if it is interrupted, this failure message comes up. So I wanted to restrict or tweak this behaviour for specific portlet so that user doesnt see this error.  Because overriding by hook might affect all portlets. Please provide suggestion or approach to handle this issue. Thanks.

Comment: So you don't want to avoid this Error, you just want to hide the message?

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation, failure method has three arguments - event, id, obj.
In some other parts of this JS file (portlet.js), event.portletId is used to fetch portlet ID. Its worth to give a try if you can fetch your portlet ID inside failure method.

Then you can apply condition on portlet ID of your choice to display the message or not.

> if (event.portletId == '<your-portlet-instance-id>') {
>
> placeHolder.placeAfter('<div class="portlet-msg-error">' +
>   Liferay.Language.get('there-was-an-unexpected-error.-please-refresh-the-current-page')
>   + '</div>');
>
> }

Comment: Thanks Harris. I shall give it a try and let you know.